# Decoding date from integer in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

In PHP, I'm saving a date record as string in order to make conditions like "more than", "less than"; but I would really like to know how to decode it. What I want to do is something like this:

The moment that record is being saved is 2014, 08/06 1:30 in 24-hours format, so my integer should be like `201408060130`, of course for this I use `date()` function.

But when it comes to decoding it to show it back like `2014, 08/06 1:30` or another format like `08/06 2014, 1:30` I really get stuck thinking on any solution for this.

I thought it would be like:

```
$date = date('YdmHm'); //Saving as 201408060130

$this->saveToDatabase($save, $mytable);

$dateDecoded = $this->getFromDatabase($mytable, $id, $theDateInteger);

$result = Date::getFormat($dateDecoded, 'YdmHm'); //Decode date format

echo $result->date('Y d/m, H:m'); //Show 2014 08/06, 1:30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple & works. Just use [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$test_value = '201408060130';

echo date('Y d/m, H:i', strtotime($test_value));
```

The output is:

> 2014 06/08, 01:30

Comment: The output should be `2014 06/08, 01:30` instead of `2014 06/08, 01:08`

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a really useful method under the *Date* class for this called [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Here is an example usage:

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('YdmHm', (string)$theDateInteger);
```

Now this is a valid datetime object which you can save to any formatting in a string if desired. For example:

```
echo $datetime->date('Y d/m, H:m');
```

Comment: your method is also useful, but i'll stay with the simpler and smaller one, thanks anyways